# How to call static file content in html page using Angular 4(typescript)?

Tags: html, angular

I want to call a variable from Constant file(Constant.ts) onto a Html Page in Select Options.

Scenario: I want to change the value of Options field depending upon the language selected by User. Suppose if he select "English",content in options field should be "abc",but if he select "Arabic" ,content should change from "abc" to "xyz".For this what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Although there are certainly many as-hoc ways to put together "translation" systems such as the one you're proposing (storing translations in constants), the bigger picture is that doing things like that becomes problematic as they are touchy, unmaintainable and full of edge cases.

Luckily, the Angular team are not deaf to our plights – this was something they noticed was being attempted every which way, so they just built it into the framework: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Internationalization is far from perfect still, but using their system will likely save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add file translation contains en.json and ar.json etc.. and you call this files when run the project and change between two lang of button,, so they just built it into the framework: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide

Comment: <select><option value="5">5 at atime</option><option value="10">10 at a time</option>     I just want to change "at a time" to arabic language that to by calling static variable in constant file using angular typescript.

Comment: yes you can this way to translate in this type {{'key' | translate}} and in json file arabic add this  key : الوقت

Comment: In this link https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide you will find information help you to apply this translate.